# Continous deployment from VSTS to my local IIS

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can any one tell me on how to configure continous deployment from VSTS to my local IIS server? Is it possible to do CI/CD to my local IIS?

Comment: If you are using Hosted agent, make sure your local machine can be accessible from internet, otherwise, you need to use a private agent.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with WinRM task?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing different about your local machine than any other machine. The same process you'd use for a server should work for your workstation. However, I fail to see the value in doing so.

Comment: Can you please provide any link which shows CD to IIS server.